# How to associate a project folder with a heroku app

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface

In some of my heroku folders, if I type something like "heroku logs" it will say that I have to use the --app option to specify what app I'm talking about. But in some folders, I can just type "heroku logs" and it automatically knows.

How does it know? How can I associate a folder with an app?

Comment: In the folders where it doesn't work are you using a different git remote name for the heroku origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will happen if you have more than one Heroku remote.  You may have one for your development environment, and another for your production environment.  Run `git remote -v` to find out.

There's no way for the heroku command to know which app you mean to interrogate with a command in those circumstances, which is why it asks you.

You can explicitly tell it to default, in these circumstances.

Say you have this:

```
$ git remote -v
prod            git@heroku.work:enter.git (fetch)
prod            git@heroku.work:enter.git (push)
staging         git@heroku.work:enter-staging.git (push)
staging         git@heroku.work:enter-staging.git (fetch)
```

Then to make `staging` the default, you can do this:

```
$ git config heroku.remote staging
```

Comment: The `heroku` command just looks for a git remote named `heroku`.  If it doesn't find one then it doesn't know which app to use.

Comment: Whoops.  I'm wrong.  Not sure if this changed recently but it actually looks for remotes that start with `git@heroku.com` or if the `heroku.remote` config is set then it uses that.  Here is the source that does that: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/base.rb